# PHP, mysqli insert_id not working

Tags: php

I have been going mad trying to work out why insert_id is returning 0 within my database. I upload an image, then upload the which category it is under and a brief description with the image_id (Which should be taken from the insert_id) I cannot figure out why it is not working.

The upload image function is :

```
function postImageShare($image_name)
{
    global $BEAR;

    if ($stmt = $BEAR->Database->prepare("INSERT INTO images SET account_name = '".$_SESSION['account_name']."', image_name = ?"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $image_name);
        $stmt->execute();
        //$stmt->close();   
    }       

    $lastItemID  = $BEAR->Database->insert_id;
    return $lastItemID; 
}
```

Then the function which Inserts the description/image_id and category (called hoard) is the following:

```
function postImageShareInformation($description, $hoard_id)
{
    global $BEAR;

    if ($stmt = $BEAR->Database->prepare("INSERT INTO imagesInformation SET account_name = '".$_SESSION['account_name']."', image_id = '$lastItemID', description = ?, hoard_id = ? "))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $description, $hoard_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close(); 
    }   

}
```

When I run the above the database is populated effectively except for the image_id is 0 everytime. When I have run the above i also get a notice in regards to $lastIteID. I tried placing the

```
        $lastItemID  = $BEAR->Database->insert_id;
```

in the second 'postImageShareInformation' function and the inserted result is still 0. Both tables hi id fields that are auto-incremementing, and $BEAR is my connection to the database. Any help would be appreciated as this issue is driving me mad.

UPDATED :

The Html :

```
<form action=" " id="share_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" id="share_image" name="share_image" style="display:none"/>
       <div id="upload-image-button" class="uibutton-upload">Choose Image</div>        
</form>
```

The above is the form to upload the image, which is done via j'query and PHP below:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#share_image').live('change', function(){ 
            $("#preview_share").html('');
            $("#preview_share").html('<div class="loading_bar"><div id="image_bar" class="bar"><span></span></div></div>');

            $("#share_form").ajaxForm({
                target: '#preview_share'
            }).submit();
    });
});
```

Then to upload the image description and hoard is via this form:

```
<form autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="form">
    <input type="text" name="description"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="hoard_id"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
 </form>
```

And this is the php which uses the functions:

```
 if(isset($_POST['description']))
{   // Set and Clean Variables
    $BEAR->Template->setData('description', $_POST['description'], TRUE);
    $BEAR->Template->setData('hoard_id', $_POST['hoard_id'], TRUE);
    $BEAR->Webprofile->postImageShareInformation($BEAR->Template->getData('description'), $BEAR->Template->getData('hoard_id'));
}

else if(isset($_FILES['share_image']) )
{
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

    $name = $_FILES['share_image']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['share_image']['size'];

    if ($size > 2097152)
    {
        echo '<div class="image_error">Photo Too Large</div>';
    }
    else if(strlen($name))
    {

        list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);

        if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
        {

            // Set Image Upload Data
            $BEAR->Template->setData('actual_image_name', $_SESSION['account_name']."-".rand().time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext);
            $tmp = $_FILES['share_image']['tmp_name'];

            // Move Location
            $location_original = "uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/";
            $location_large = "uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/large/";
            $location_small = "uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/small/";

            if (!file_exists("uploads/test/" . $_SESSION['account_name']))
            {

                mkdir($location_original, 0744);
                mkdir($location_small, 0744);
                mkdir($location_large, 0744);

                move_uploaded_file($tmp, $location_original.$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'));
                $BEAR->Assets->create_thumb(125, 125, $location_original, $BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'), $location_small);
                $BEAR->Assets->create_thumb(500, 500, $location_original, $BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'), $location_large);

                echo "<img src='uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/large/".$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name')."'class='preview'>".$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name');
            }
            else
            {
                // Move Image
                move_uploaded_file($tmp, $location_original.$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'));
                $BEAR->Assets->create_thumb(125, 125, $location_original, $BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'), $location_small);
                $BEAR->Assets->create_thumb(500, 500, $location_original, $BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'), $location_large);  

                $BEAR->Webprofile->postImageShare($BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'));
                echo "<img src='uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/small/".$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name')."' class='preview'>";
            } 
        }
        else 
        {
            echo '<div class="image_error">Invalid File Type</div>';
        }                       
    }                        
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="image_error">Failed</div>';
    }
}
```

All the above allows the user to preview the uploaded image before submitting the description and Hoard ID.Hope this helps.

Comment: is function `postImageShare($image_name)` returning correct `$lastItemID`?

Comment: Hi @LoneWOLFs I tested the code and it does return the latest ID, so that is working, its just getting it to work for my next function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that your function `postImageShareInformation($description, $hoard_id)` is not getting the `$lastItemID` variable. So try passing the value of `$lastItemID` in the function itself like below.

```
function postImageShareInformation($description, $hoard_id, $lastItemID)
{
    global $BEAR;

    if ($stmt = $BEAR->Database->prepare("INSERT INTO imagesInformation SET account_name = '".$_SESSION['account_name']."', image_id = '".$lastItemID."', description = ?, hoard_id = ? "))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $description, $hoard_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close(); 
    }   

}
```

**To the updated question**

You were calling `postImageShareInformation()` function before calling `postImageShare()` function.  Thus it would never get the `$lastItemID`. I've modified your code assuming you use my new modified functions.  But this should still give you an idea.

```
if(isset($_FILES['share_image']) )
{
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

    $name = $_FILES['share_image']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['share_image']['size'];

    if ($size > 2097152)
    {
        echo '<div class="image_error">Photo Too Large</div>';
    }
    else if(strlen($name))
    {

        list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);

        if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
        {

            // Set Image Upload Data
            $BEAR->Template->setData('actual_image_name', $_SESSION['account_name']."-".rand().time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext);
            $tmp = $_FILES['share_image']['tmp_name'];

            // Move Location
            $location_original = "uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/";
            $location_large = "uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/large/";
            $location_small = "uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/small/";

            if (!file_exists("uploads/test/" . $_SESSION['account_name']))
            {

                mkdir($location_original, 0744);
                mkdir($location_small, 0744);
                mkdir($location_large, 0744);

                move_uploaded_file($tmp, $location_original.$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'));
                $BEAR->Assets->create_thumb(125, 125, $location_original, $BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'), $location_small);
                $BEAR->Assets->create_thumb(500, 500, $location_original, $BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'), $location_large);

                echo "<img src='uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/large/".$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name')."'class='preview'>".$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name');
            }
            else
            {
                // Move Image
                move_uploaded_file($tmp, $location_original.$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'));
                $BEAR->Assets->create_thumb(125, 125, $location_original, $BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'), $location_small);
                $BEAR->Assets->create_thumb(500, 500, $location_original, $BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'), $location_large);  

                // This will return $lastItemID which we will pass now to postImageShareInformation() function in the block below.
                $lastItemID = $BEAR->Webprofile->postImageShare($BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name'));

                if(isset($_POST['description']))
                {   // Set and Clean Variables
                    $BEAR->Template->setData('description', $_POST['description'], TRUE);
                    $BEAR->Template->setData('hoard_id', $_POST['hoard_id'], TRUE);
                    //You were calling this function before ...
                    $BEAR->Webprofile->postImageShareInformation($BEAR->Template->getData('description'), $BEAR->Template->getData('hoard_id'),$lastItemID);
                }
                echo "<img src='uploads/test/".$_SESSION['account_name']."/small/".$BEAR->Template->getData('actual_image_name')."' class='preview'>";
            } 
        }
        else 
        {
            echo '<div class="image_error">Invalid File Type</div>';
        }                       
    }                        
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="image_error">Failed</div>';
    }
}
```

This should work...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LoneWolfs When trying to above code, the following Warning occurs - 'Missing argument 3 for postImageShareInformation()' and the same Notice: undefined varibale:lastItemID. It seems that the postImageShareInformation cannot get the $lastItemId variable... any thoughts? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @LeeMarshall Yes check the function i modified it and i am now passing a third variable as the `$lastItemID` so you should call your function with 3 parameters the last being `$lastItemID`.  So your fn will look like this when its called `postImageShareInformation('I am image description', 1, 100)` where 100 is the data returned by `postImageShare($image_name)` function for example.

Comment: This is exactly what I did got the error, it seems like the second function cannot get the $lastItemID. The first function is activated by j'query with the following code in the page header  $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#share_image').live('change', function(){ 
                $("#preview_share").html('');
                $("#preview_share").html('<div class="loading_bar"><div id="image_bar" class="bar"><span></span></div></div>');

                $("#share_form").ajaxForm({
                    target: '#preview_share'
                }).submit();
        });
    });

Comment: But that shouldn't have any effect as the function is still submitting the image effectively into the database.

Comment: @LeeMarshall show me the html and how these functions are called.  Error is in the way you call them.  As it there's nothing wrong with the functions.

Comment: I updated the question with Html and Jquery... Hope that helps, and thanks for your time.

Comment: @LeeMarshall Check my updated answer if it helps you resolve your query

Comment: I will be checking this tonight, and will let you know... If it works I will make it answered. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is because your tables' id column doesn't have an AUTO_INCREMENT property

Answer (score 0):

Now I understood what's happening here. So we have those 2 functions:

```
function postImageShare($image_name)
{
    global $BEAR;

    if ($stmt = $BEAR->Database->prepare("INSERT INTO images SET account_name = '".$_SESSION['account_name']."', image_name = ?"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $image_name);
        $stmt->execute();
        //$stmt->close();   
    }       

    $lastItemID  = $BEAR->Database->insert_id;
    return $lastItemID; 
}
```

and

```
// Note that I've added a new parameter to this function and also
// I've modified your prepare statement
function postImageShareInformation($description, $hoard_id, $lastItemID)
{
    global $BEAR;

    if ($stmt = $BEAR->Database->prepare("INSERT INTO imagesInformation SET account_name = '".$_SESSION['account_name']."', image_id = ?, description = ?, hoard_id = ? "))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $lastItemID, $description, $hoard_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close(); 
    }   

}
```

Now, when we call the first one we have to assign the returned id to a variable:

```
$lastItemID = postImageShare("myImageName");
```

When we call the second function we can assign this variable to the last parameter:

```
postImageShareInformation("My description", 13, $lastItemID);
```

Now should be just fine!

Answer (score -1):

I assume that $Bear object is not a direct mysqli connection.. It is a class created by you?

If you have

```
$mysqli = new MySQLi($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
```

then after you run the query

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('test')");
```

you can get the last inserted id by

```
$mysqli->insert_id
```

Comment: Hi Matei, the $BEAR is in my function __construct. Which is basically $this->Database = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db) ... So surely me using $BEAR->Database->insert_id this should return the last id? or am i missing something?

Answer (score -1):

MySQL provides this functionality in the `last_insert_id()` function.